# how can we have TableViewCell in three columns

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to have an image and label in a tableview with like 3 images in a row in 3 columns. how can we divide the tableviewcell in 3 columns and repeat the same image and label in 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stonz is right, You need to use a prototype and add some code  in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // use a prototype cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"imageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //ImageViews
    UIImageView *image1 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stack"]];
    UIImageView *image2 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
     [image2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"super"]];
    UIImageView *image3 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
     [image3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"android"]];

    //Label
    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    label1.text = @"Stackoverflow";
    UILabel *label2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
    label2.text = @"Superuser";
    UILabel *label3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
    label3.text = @"Android";

    return cell;

}
```

---

I created a <kbd>[DEMO PROJECT](https://mega.co.nz/#!rVpnwAjT!oqwI0mdA0_diDUoRYrIykNsgCYSyU9rzmoAF8sUT380)</kbd> for you

and here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrGDe.png)

Comment: Thank you very much meda. The images and labels should be dynamic though because i am not going to have the same image and label in all the rows

Comment: These are dynamic prototype cell , its up 2  u to load your images

Comment: Thank you meda. I understood. Can you tell me one more design question. This is iPAD application, suppose I have 6 images, say like in 3 images in a row which is like 2 rows there will be no scroll also should I go for table view or should I do static images. Like I will have these kind of screens may 6 or 7 in my application but with different images. Please let me know

Comment: I did click resolved, but does it show as resolved. I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create custom `UITableViewCell`s in order to achieve this. The standard cells are very limited in what they can display. There are several tutorials online (just Google "custom uitableviewcell") Here is one: [Table View Cells](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702)

Comment: Thank you. I know how to create a custom cell, can you please tell me how to create 3 columns.

Comment: You would arrange the labels and images inside the custom cell where you want them to go. Thats how you create 3 columns.

Comment: Are you saying that you want 3 separately-scrolling columns? So scrolling down in column 2 would keep column 1 and 3 where they are?

Comment: I wanted like 3 columns that's why instead of going for TableViewCell, I should go for UICollectionView